# iOS Provisioning profile doesn't include sandbox entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, provisioning-profile, appstore-sandbox

I'm getting the following error while uploading the iOS build from Xcode:

**Profile doesn't include the com.apple.security.app-sandbox and com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write entitlements**

[Xcode upload error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCN7C.jpg)

I have also created an .entitlements file turning on both sandbox and user selected rights. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9d6g.jpg)

I can also see the required entitlements in signing and capabilities tab under app's target section. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8w4M.jpg)

I have also tried deleting all provisioning files from

> ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/

and re-downloading them again.

The build is getting succeeded but I'm not able to upload it to app store connect.

Any help or suggestions will mean a lot. Thanks!